# How to split the file in Bourne Shell with the number of split files in the filename

Tags: shell, split, sh

I need to split a larger file. I use the following command to split.

```
split -l 100 ./myFile.csv myFile
```

This creates a file myFileaa, myFileab, myFileac.....

But I want a different naming format. For example the total number of files getting split is 4, I want the filenames something like this

```
myFile1_4
myFile2_4
myFile3_4
myFile4_4
```

Can anyone please help how to get the filenames like this? Thanks.

Comment: How is the fact that you use Bourne shell (if really you do -- POSIX sh is ubiquitous, but Bourne is only ever found on older Solaris these days) relevant? `split` is a separate UNIX command; it does not come with your shell, and thus behaves the same way regardless of which shell you're using (or if you invoke it without a shell at all).

Comment: Bad luck on being condemned to use Bourne shell.  It is probably simplest to rename the generated files after you know how many there are; I don't think there's a prescient version of `split` that can tell how many files there will be (since in general the input could come from a pipeline and there's no way to know in advance how big the input will be).  Anything else is troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish that just use additional *GNU* `split` parameters:

```
split -l 100 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=_4 myFile
```

- `numeric-suffixes` - add number to the file name instead of characters
- `additional-suffix` - adds suffix after file number

See more options with `man split` or `split --help`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I use Bourne shell. numeric-suffixes and additional-suffix parameters are not available for me.

Comment: @Sree, `split` does not come with your shell, so which shell you use has no bearing on its options.

Comment: @Sree, also, are you very sure you use Bourne? `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not Bourne -- Bourne is a shell from the 70s that allows `^` instead of `|` and doesn't support `$()` for expansions. There's only one operating system I know of shipped inside the last decade that has a Bourne implementation at all.

Comment: I am getting "split: illegal option -- numeric-suffixes=1" error message

Comment: @Sree, that's no surprise; `split` isn't required to support any option not in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/split.html, and the options @Grzegorz mentioned look like GNU extensions from the naming. The point I was making is only that your split would still not have those options even if you were using bash.

Comment: I am not familiar with shell interpreters. I use this line at the very beginning of my .sh file "#!/bin/sh"

Comment: @Sree, `#!/bin/sh` does not make your script Bourne on modern operating systems; it makes it POSIX sh. And, again, `split` is not part of your shell, so which shell you use HAS NO IMPACT WHATSOEVER on which options `split` does or does not support.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. I dont get these suffix parameters in the man page itself

Comment: @Sree, yes, your man page will be specific to the platform you're on, and no platform is required to implement any parameters beyond those in the POSIX specification I linked.

Comment: [http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/split/](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/split/) posix standards does not have numeric suffix

Answer (score 2):

One option is to implement `split`'s functionality yourself.

This implementation assumes that your `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not actual 1970s-era Bourne.

```
#!/bin/sh
input_file="$1"
output_prefix="$2"
lines_per_file=${3:-100}
total_count=$(wc -l <"$input_file")
total_splits=$(( total_count / lines_per_file ))

if [ "$input_file" ]; then
  exec <"$input_file"
fi

# handle remainder
lines_handled=$(( total_splits * lines_per_file ))
if [ "$lines_handled" -lt "$total_count" ]; then
  total_splits=$(( total_splits + 1 ))
fi

current_split=1
lines_left=$lines_per_file
exec >"${output_prefix}${current_split}_${total_splits}"
while read -r; do
  printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
  lines_left=$(( lines_left - 1 ))
  if [ "$lines_left" -le 0 ]; then
    current_split=$(( current_split + 1 ))
    exec >"${input_file}_${current_split}_${total_splits}"
    lines_left=$lines_per_file
  fi
done
```

You can save the above as `numeric-split`, and then run:

```
./numeric-split myFile.csv myFile 100
```

If you're running this on Solaris 10 (the only modern-ish operating system to ship an actual Bourne shell), please edit the shebang to point to `#!/bin/ksh` instead; modern `ksh` is a superset of POSIX sh, whereas Bourne shell predates the standard by almost two decades.